# Best way to utilise an include file which just includes an array in PHP

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Kohana's config files look like this.. here is an example of a database config file (simplified)

```
return array(
    'dbhost' => 'localhost',
    'user'   => 'Tom_Jones'
);
```

I've also got a CMS which wants the connection details. Whilst the CMS uses a different user (with more rights), I'd like to know the best way to include this file and get the data out of it (so as to not repeat myself for hostname and dbname).

I haven't thought up of any elegant solutions yet and have not yet dug around Kohana to see how it does it. It's late Friday here so it's probably really obvious to everyone except me.

### Update

My apologies, I forgot to include that this is using [Kohana 3](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/download)!

Comment: Alex, I just downloaded Kohana to see what you mean, and every config file I see looks like `$config['whatever'] = array(...` Is it possible you over simplified what you are looking to do? The code you provided can't be included (if that is how the file starts and ends) and used without something like `file_get_contents` and an `eval`. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry Doug, I should of specified it was for Kohana 3, which uses the new way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kohana v3, in the `Kohana_Config_Reader` class, method `load()`:

```
$config = Arr::merge($config, require $file);
```

`require $file` is used to load the array in the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Kohana and could not files that look like your example, but if you are using the  current version you could repurpose the config files like this:

```
<?php
  // Your script
  define('SYSPATH', 'true'); // So Kohana doesn't kill our script
  $config = array();
  include('path/to/system/config/database.php');

  echo $config['default']['connection']['user']; // Echos database user
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it was for the new version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.php.net/function.include says:

> Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would a normal function.

Let's take your example code

```
<?php // test2.php
return array(
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'user'   => 'Tom_Jones'
);
```

and a script that includes test2.php

```
<?php
$cfg = include 'test2.php';
if ( !is_array($cfg) ) {
    // ... add useful error handling here ...
}
// you might want to test the structure of $cfg
// before accessing specific elements
echo $cfg['dbhost'];
```

prints `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/about.configuration) contains some basic info on how you access those config files. So if you have the following in a file called  `db.php` in `application/config`:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

return array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user'   => 'Tom_Jones'
);
```

You'd access them like this:

```
$options = Kohana::config('db');
echo $options['user'];
echo $options['host'];
```

Or like this:

```
echo Kohana::config('db.user');
echo Kohana::config('db.host');
```

Or like this:

```
echo Kohana::config('db')->user;
echo Kohana::config('db')->host;
```